# Why are "disabled" snap versions not removed automatically

Tags: snap

The command "snap list --all" shows multiple versions of same snaps installed. It is an issue since some of the snaps occupy large space. Furthermore the average user will have no inkling of the issue.
I have screenshot:
[image: Disabled apps]
Why was this chosen by Canonical.

Comment: First of all, don't post screenshots of terminal text output. Copy and paste the text into your question and format properly.

Comment: You can see the sizes with `ls -l /var/lib/snapd/snaps`.

Answer (score 4):

> Why are “disabled” snap versions not removed automatically

They are.

Mind that snap keeps three revisions by default

```
snap set system refresh.retain=N
```

to configure the amount of revisions where N>=2.